# Is it not possible to change this route after initial load?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to update the path to Firebase RTDB when I click a button, but angular won't allow. I am using angular-fire.

This is the HTML

```
<button type="button" (click)='race_no("race_no_2")'>Race 2</button>


  <div *ngFor="let item of items | async">
       <p *ngFor="let race_lineup of item.lineups[0].race_lineup"     >{{ race_lineup.name }}</p>
</div>
```

This is the Component

```
import { Component, OnChanges, OnInit, SimpleChanges, Inject } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']

  
})
export class AppComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit {
  items: Observable<any[]>;
  
  x = "race_no_1";
  
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
          this.items = this.db.list(this.x).valueChanges();

  
  }

  ngOnChanges(x: SimpleChanges) {
    this.items = this.db.list(this.x).valueChanges();  
console.log(this.x)
  }  
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  race_no(b: string){
this.x = b;
  }

}
```

I am expecting that when the button is clicked **ngOnChanges** is triggered due to the fact that the string x would have changed.

```
  ngOnChanges(x: SimpleChanges) {
    this.items = this.db.list(this.x).valueChanges();  
console.log(this.x)
  }
```

Using **HTTP.Get** the same behaviour works just fine, seems like ngOnChanges don't even recognize the change here.

What is wrong here ?

Comment: `ngOnChanges` is used to react to changes to `@input` bindings and will not detect changes to local variables.

https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges

Is there anything stopping you from placing the logic directly inside your `race_no` method?

Comment: You are right. That worked no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a `BehaviorSubject` for that

```
items$: Observable<any[]>;
x$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('race_no_1');

constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.items$ = this.x$.pipe(switchMap((x) => {
        return this.db.list(x).valueChanges();
    }
}

race_no(b: string) {
    this.x$.next(b);
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't normally add a negative comment but the fact that this got marked as the correct answer is too much. Why on earth would you want to overcomplicate it like this? Subjects are generally used for cross component communication, there is absolutelty no need for one here. It works yes but this is terrible advice.

Comment: Well that's how a stream of data works in angular. Change detection in angular is usually triggered each time an input changes, which results in way too many calculations. In the case mentioned by the OP it would mean that a webrequest is sent each time any input changes. Using rxjs (or the newly introduced signals) reduces the number of calculations and allows you to use OnPush change detection

Comment: Off course you could put the calculation in the click handler itself, but that would prevent you from extending your code if necessary

Answer (score 1):

As Sam Scholefield mentioned to me. Just add the logic to the race_no method.

```
 race_no(b: string){
    this.items = this.db.list(b).valueChanges();  
  }
```